# How to plot a colored helix whose color varies in the curve through a function?

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, color, plot

I have a problem on how to color the plot of a helix using pgfplots. Let the helix be given by $\alpha(\phi) = (\cos(\phi),\sin(\phi),\phi)$, for $0 \leq \phi \leq 2\pi$, then I need the color of the curve to vary according to a function. More specifically, I would like the color of the plot to be black at $\phi = 0$ and at $\phi = 2\pi$, but that it gets more and more bluish when close to $\phi = \pi$.

I was able to plot this curve in just a single color, as in the example below:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{width=10cm, compat=1.9}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    scaled ticks=false,
    ticks=none,
    view={45}{30},
    ]
\addplot3+[domain=0:2*pi, samples=100, samples y=0,no marks, smooth,line width=.5mm,color=blue](
  {cos(deg(x))},
  {sin(deg(x))},
  {x}
);
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You only need to replace `color=blue` by `mesh`. (I also switched to a more modern compatibility mode.)

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{width=10cm, compat=1.17}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    scaled ticks=false,
    ticks=none,
    view={45}{30},
    ]
\addplot3+[domain=0:2*pi, samples=100, samples y=0,no marks, 
    smooth,line width=.5mm,mesh](
  {cos(deg(x))},
  {sin(deg(x))},
  {x}
);
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

It is possible to change the coloring by changing `point meta` (the default value of which is `z`, you can make it an arbitrary function of `x`, `y`, `z`) and/or changing the `color map`.

Comment: One can also get rid of the `deg` by dialing `trig format plots=rad`.

Comment: This solved my problem. Thanks!